# Free parking in Bath UK

Tags: uk, automobiles, bath-england

Where can I park in Bath for free, so that it's convenient for the town centre? I will be there 22nd Dec - 29th Dec, so on both holidays and normal weekdays.

Comment: Do you just want to park for a few hours, or do you want to leave your car somewhere for the whole 7 days?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: you can't, sorry :/ Parking is at a premium in the tight and narrow streets of Bath.

Long answer comes from [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Bath):

> It is very easy to get lost in Bath, as a lot of it is one-way and
>   there's a traffic system that prevents you driving from one side of
>   the city to the other. You have to go out on an unofficial ring road
>   and re-enter the city. Furthermore, the high population density, the
>   lack of a city bypass and the low capacity of the old narrow streets
>   means that congestion is often horrendous. In particular, on Saturdays
>   the car parks will all be full, and the roads will be blocked by
>   people queueing to get into these car parks, a problem made worse
>   since the opening of the new Southgate car park. At peak times, it can
>   be quicker to walk from the edge of Bath to town, rather than driving
>   and finding somewhere to park. The short answer - don't drive in Bath.
>
> Parking in central Bath is often a nightmare and two hour limits apply
>   on many streets. Most of the smaller long stay car parks will be full
>   by 8:30AM during the working week so you have to get in early. Major
>   central multi-storey car parks are based at Walcot Street, Manvers
>   Street (near the train stations) and Charlotte Street (off Queens
>   Square). Average 2010 rates are around £3 an hour - or the more
>   prohibitive pay and display in central bath at £1.30p per 30 minutes
>   in the most convenient street locations. Many parking bays are
>   "residents parking only" so check before leaving your car. Traffic
>   wardens are very efficient so don't even think of parking on a yellow
>   line or going over your time limit. On Sundays and between 7PM and 8AM
>   other days most parking is free, however check machines for exact
>   details.
>
> The best way to drive into town is to use the park and ride facilities
>   [12] when travelling into Bath for the day. You can park for free and
>   then take a bus for £2.20 per adult return (round-trip, discounts
>   exist) right into the city. The only downside to this is that the last
>   bus leaves at 8:30PM, so you can't use this service if you're staying
>   in Bath late.

Comment: Yep, we have just came back and I can confirm that this is indeed the case.

Comment: Are you a local?

Comment: @LoSauer nope. I used to live in London, but am now in Australia.

Answer (score 4):

I know the date has passed - but for future reference you might consider 2 options -- not free - but maybe cheaper than council or NCP:

- [ParkatmyHouse](http://www.parkatmyhouse.com/) - from the site: *created to connect home and business owners who would like to earn money from renting their space with drivers in need of a convenient, safe and cost-effective place to park.*

  Not just Bath, but the whole UK! Particularly popular places include Twickenham, Surrey/London for the Rugby - and I'd imagine those with parking areas in Bath would be popular too for the same reason.
- [Raileasy](http://www.raileasy.co.uk/) - If there is any possibility that a car is not needed - this site is aimed at travel to various events that have rail stations nearby.

(I have no involvement in either service.)